# Concentration bound on maximum subset sum of standard Gaussians

Tags: pr.probability, measure-concentration, gaussian

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be standard Gaussians. Let $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \{A \in 2^{\{1, \dots, n\}} : |A| = k\} $ be a family of subsets of $\{1,\dots, n\}$ with fixed size $k$. [Note that $\mathcal{S}$ may be smaller than $\{A \in 2^{\{1, \dots, n\}} : |A| = k\}$, the set of all subsets with fixed size $k$.]

Let $Y = \max_{A \in \mathcal{S}} \sum_{i \in A} X_i$. Are there any known concentration bounds on $Y$? I have the bound $E[Y] \leq \sqrt{2k\log{|\mathcal{S}|}}$, and I want to say something like "We have $Y < 10 \sqrt{k \log{|\mathcal{S}|}}$ with high probability".

I tried using Chebyshev with the bound $\text{Var}(\max Z_i) \leq \sum \text{Var}(Z_i)$, but that yields $\text{Var}(Y) \leq O(k |\mathcal{S}|)$ which is too weak.

Comment: In order statistics, you would ask this as: What are concentration bounds for $\sum_{i>n-k}X_{(i)}$, where $X$ is a standard normal?

Comment: It's a bit different since $\mathcal{S}$ is not _all_ subsets of size k. I'll reword it since it's unclear.

Comment: That makes sense. How is the family specified? The family $\{\{1,2,3,4\},\{5,6,7,8\}\}$ vs the family $\{\{4,5,6,7\},\{5,6,7,8\}\}$ would give quite different results.

Comment: Is there a lower bound on the size of S? Obviously concentration fails if S and k are small.

Comment: Yeah, I assume |S| grows with n. I think I have a proof in this case actually, which I'll write out.

Comment: @UthsavChitra See below for a strong bound based on Borell-TIS inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claim: If $|\mathcal{S}| \to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$, then $Y \leq \sqrt{2k\log{|\mathcal{S}|}}$ with high probability.

Proof: Let $t = \sqrt{2k\log{|\mathcal{S}|}}$. By union bound, we have

$P(Y > t) \leq \sum_{A \in \mathcal{S}} P(\sum_{i \in A} X_i > t) = |\mathcal{S}| \cdot P(N(0,k) > t)$.

Plugging in $t$ and simplifying yields $P(Y > t) \leq |\mathcal{S}| \cdot P(N(0,1) > \sqrt{2\log{|\mathcal{S}|}})$.

Using the bound here (https://www.johndcook.com/blog/norm-dist-bounds/) yields
$P(Y > t) \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\log{|\mathcal{S}|}}}$, which goes to $0$ as $n \to\infty$.

Comment: There are much better bounds. Google "Borell-TIS inequality"

Answer (score 2):

For a subcollection $\mathcal S$ of $k$-element subsets of $[n]$, consider the random variable $Z_{\mathcal S} := \sup_{A \in \mathcal S}|X_A|$, where $X_A:=\sum_{i \in A}X_i$, and the $X_i$'s are iid from $N(0,1)$.
Note that $X_A \sim N(0,k)$. Note that $(X_A)_A$ is a Gaussian process on $\mathcal S$ seen as a topological space. Moreover, it is a standard computation that
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb E Z_{\mathcal S} &= \mathbb E \sup_{A \in \mathcal S}|X_A| \le \sqrt{2k\log|\mathcal S|} < \infty,\\
 \sigma_{\mathcal S}^2 &:= \sup_{A \in \mathcal S}\mathbb E|X_A|^2 = k < \infty,
\end{split}
$$
where the first line is thanks to [Massart's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_complexity). Therefore, noting that $Z_{\mathcal S} \ge \sup_{A \in \mathcal S}X_A$, the [Borell-TIS ienquality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borell%E2%80%93TIS_inequality) gives

$$
\begin{split}
\forall u \ge 0,\; \mathbb P\left(\sup_{A \in \mathcal S}X_A \ge \sqrt{2k\log|\mathcal S|} + u\right) &\le \mathbb P(Z_{\mathcal S} \ge \sqrt{2k\log|\mathcal S|} + u)\\
&\le  \mathbb P(Z_{\mathcal S} \ge \mathbb EZ_{\mathcal S} + u)\\
&\le \exp(-u^2/(2\sigma_{\mathcal S}^2))\\
& = \exp(-u^2/(2k)).
\end{split}
$$

To make things more interpretable, we do the the change of variable $t:=u/\sqrt{2k}$ to get
$$
\mathbb P\left(\sup_{A \in \mathcal S}X_A \le \sqrt{2k}(\sqrt{\log|\mathcal S|} + t)\right) \le e^{-t^2},\forall t \ge 0.
$$

In particular, if $|\mathcal S| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, then taking $t = \sqrt{\log |\mathcal S|}$ gives
$$
\mathbb P\left(\sup_{A \in \mathcal S}X_A \le \sqrt{8k\log|\mathcal S|}\right) \le 1/|\mathcal S| \to 0.
$$